# Spring validation for incompatible types

Tags: java, spring, validation

I have a simple form which contains 2 fields:

```
  @Component
public class AddToCartForm {
    @NotNull
    private Long phoneId;

    @Min(value = 1L, message = "Quantity should be integer positive number")
    @NotNull
    private Long quantity;

    public void setPhoneId(Long phoneId) {
        this.phoneId = phoneId;
    }

    public void setQuantity(Long quantity) {
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }

    public Long getPhoneId() {
        return phoneId;
    }

    public Long getQuantity() {
        return quantity;
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody
    ModelAndView addPhone(@Validated AddToCartForm form, BindingResult result) throws InvalidAddToCartFormException {
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView(new MappingJackson2JsonView());
        if(result.hasErrors()){
            throw new InvalidAddToCartFormException(result.getFieldError().getDefaultMessage());
        }
        else {
            cartService.addPhone(form.getPhoneId(), form.getQuantity());
            mv.addObject("itemsAmount", cartService.getCart().getItemsAmount());
            mv.addObject("subtotal", cartService.getCart().getSubtotal());
            mv.setStatus(HttpStatus.OK);
        }
        return mv;
    }
@ExceptionHandler(InvalidAddToCartFormException.class)
    public @ResponseBody @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST) String handleInvalidAddToCartException(InvalidAddToCartFormException e){
        return e.getMessage();
    }
```

The problem is when I try to input something like "qwe" I get `NumberFormatException` in message instead of "value should be positive", is there any way to handle such inputs in a good way?

Comment: Can you add the code of your controller please ?

Comment: if you are using hibernate validation then maybe you can use `@Digits`

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html
The reference here shows that you can validate the object. Which means the values are assigned to the object.  NumberFormatException comes when it is initializing the property of that object so its before validator even coming into execution. I would need the logic where you are initializing your MyForm.

Comment: The validation annotation is not Validated but Valid.

Comment: added controller code

Comment: added form class

Comment: @Digits didnt help

Answer (score 0):

Change @Validated annotation to @Valid (from javax.validation).

Also, you don't need to implement your own exception. Spring will automatically throws exception before it reach your code if the form is not valid.

Comment: It didnt help, i steel get numberFormatException in message

Comment: So what? I need to show error message to user but not get an NumberFormatException. If user's input is incorrect i need to show error msg near the input field and not redirect him to error page or smth like this. And i can not use <form: errors> cuz i'm using ajax for adding phones to cart so ajax is to show then this message